# Как присвоить имена из столбца row считанной из БД к объекту self построчно

Tags: python, sqlite

Возник вопрос, я считал с sqlite столбец с именами и пытаюсь построчно присвоить ее объекту класса self, но при попытке написать индекс присваиваются буквы сразу всех строк. Я новичек в программировании и не знаю как сделать это правильно, а поиск мне не помог.

```
con = sqlite3.connect("D:/Dataset/Dataset.db")
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Person")
    while True:
        row = cur.fetchone()
        if row == None:
            break
        self.sql = row [1]
        self.name_known_list[0] = self.sql[0:20]
        print (self.name_known_list[0])
        print (type(self.name_known_list[0]))
```

Вывод print:

[image: Вывод print]

В моем случае нужно чтобы первый элемент name_know_list являлся первой строкой из БД. И это лучшее что я придумал.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мы не знаем что представляют из себя `self.sql` и `self.name_known_list`, поэтому отвечу на вопрос как в цикле пройтись по записям возвращенным `cur.execute(...)`:

```
con = sqlite3.connect("D:/Dataset/Dataset.db")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Person")
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row)
    # process single record here ...
```

Если вам нужна единственная запись:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Person LIMIT 1")
row = cur.fetchone()
...
```

---

**Возьмите на заметку:**
В БД нет понятия - *первая запись*, если не указана явная сортировка с `ORDER BY ...`.